# UITableview only scrolling to middle - Swift 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, swift4

I have a table view with chat messages in it. I am trying to scroll to the bottom of the tableview but it only scrolls half way. I suspect this has to do with the cells being a different height (as some messages are longer than others).

Is there a way to scroll to the bottom completely and not base it on an average cell height?

Here is the code I am using to scroll to the bottom:

```
let lastIndex = IndexPath(row: messages.count - 1, section: 0)
self.tableview.scrollToRow(at: lastIndex, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using TableView Extension**

```
import UIKit

    extension UITableView {
        func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool) {
            let y = contentSize.height - frame.size.height
            setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: (y<0) ? 0 : y), animated: animated)
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
tableView.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
```